# How to reveal (and hide) button after typing in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am quite good in jQuery, but Angular is not (yet!) one of my strongest skills. I have the below JSFiddle in jQuery, but now it turns out I can't use jQuery, so I am forced to use Angular.

http://jsfiddle.net/eAt6Q/1/

What I want to do, is to show a button after typing something in an input field and removing it when the input field is blank (so at the initial state or when backspacing and there is no letter left), just like in the example.

How would I do this? How do I bind a button to a keypress, because I am struggling to find that out.

I have tried something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="testInput" />
   <button ng-if="testInput.length"></button>

<input type="text" id="testInput" />
   <button ng-hide="testInput.length"></button>
```

But this is not working and I know for sure I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-model` is all you need in angular

```
<input type="text" id="testInput" ng-model="testInput" />
<button ng-show="testInput !== null "></button>
```

You can use `ng-blur` for more actions

Comment: Oh my God... so easy, yet so effective! Thanks man, I love this! I have upvoted you and will accept the answer. Oh btw: is it possible to animate it too?

Comment: Thanks mate! Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ng-show or ng-if both to hide the button but ng-if more suitable to hide button from dom

```
<input type="text" id="testInput" ng-model="testInput" />
<button ng-if="testInput !== null || testInput.length > 0"></button>
```

or you can also use ng-disabled to disabled the button without hide.